# Google bigQuery latest revision

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-java-client

As a maven user I wanted to know where to find the **latest** bigQuery revision.

Actually i am retrieving it from the [Api wiki on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#BigQuery_API) but not sure that's the latest one as specified :

> *NOTE: the latest revision number (rev#) on the server may be slightly higher than what's specified here.*

I am asking this question cause I read [the article posted yesterday](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.fr/2013/03/bigquery-gets-big-new-features-to-make.html) (14/03) annoucing some changes on BQ like the introducing of TIMESTAMP field but I can't make it work using the following revision

> v2-rev67-1.13.2-beta

Comment: My timestamp data were rejected cause of wrong format, but i am still interested in knowing where to find the latest rev :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated the Maven Repo on 3/13/2013.

Information about the latest Java libs are here: 
https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/apis/bigquery/v2?lang=java

Sample pom.xml additions:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>google-api-services</id>
      <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev67-1.13.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```